# Forgot the Pattern lock pattern in lollipop. How di i reset it?

Tags: android-device-manager, pattern-lock

I locked my mobile with pattern lock. I forgot the pattern. In lollipop there is no option "Forget Pattern". I used Android Device Manager to lock my mobile. It Locked. But I does not ask for the password. The Mobile Screen is like bellow. How to Reset it?

[image: Locked Form Android Device Manager]

Answer (score 0):

The first and easiest way is resetting that Tushar's answer is about. I'm afraid there is no physical offline way to bypass the lock.

Although, there are apps that have access to the lock screen and can actually bypass it.

For example [**Samsung's Knox**](https://docs.samsungknox.com/KC-Getting-Started/Content/Lock_and_unlock_devices.htm) and **Google device manager** (Read a howto [here](https://one.comodo.com/blog/itsm/unlock-your-android-device-using-android-device-manager.php)), but they have prerequisites. You need to sync your device with them. If you have, be happy. If you have not, I can think of other ways.

Answer (score -1):

Follow following steps -

1. Switch off your phone
2. Now hold the "volume up + home button + power button" until the phone boots (if you device doesn’t have a home button just hold together volume up key and power button.
3. Now a screen like DOS will come up with different options. Use the volume key to move up and down then scroll down to "Restore Factory Defaults" or "Delete all User Data”" depending on which is on your device.
4. After following the steps above, scroll down to "Reboot System" and wait for your phone to reboot.

Comment: Any option Without Reseting??